# Become first responder app delegate not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextfield, appdelegate

My situation goes as follows: I have an app which has a PIN screen implemented. Its nothing high-tech just basic 4 `UITextField`s and implemented logic via `UITextFieldDelegate` - it works.

I'm showing this screen in app delegate on `-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` event. I am using `MMDrawerController` from github (link: https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) as the main view controller. If the current view presented when the application enters background and foreground again is this `MMDrawerController` then the `becomeFirstResponder` is not working - it doesn't show the keyboard. If there is another view controller presented on top of drawer controller the when entering foreground (let's say settings view) then keyboard appears normally.

I have tried `NSLog`ing the `canBecomeFirstResponder` property and its set to `YES`. What is going on? How to fix this?

I can paste code if needed but its nothing ambiguous. Just plain call `becomeFirstResponder`.

**EDIT:**

To explain things a bit more clearly. `rootViewController` is a view controller caleed `LoginViewController` and it `alloc-init`s the sidebar and the center view controllers, `alloc-init`s the drawer controller and hooks everything up so it works. The app delegate view is actually a PIN screen which pops up when the app enters foreground. Now the keyboard appears like it should for the first time the drawer is visible.

When the user pops up `SettingsViewController` (yes, this is another view controller accessible from the sidebar view controller) it works as well. But when the user dismisses the settings view controller keyboard doesn't appear anymore. It has to do something with the drawer cause I tried without it and it worked (but I only had sidebar or center view controller visible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would want to access the textField within the MMDrawerControllers currentView. I have achieved something similar with this implementation:

In your app delegate store a reference to the DrawerController like so:

In AppDels interface:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) MMDrawerController *appDrawController;
```

Then after you create the local drawer controller in didFinishLaunching (if you followed the setup instructions for this library):

```
self.appDrawController = drawerController;
```

In your applicationWillEnterForeground:

```
THECLASSTHATCONTAINSTHEPINVIEW *yourClass = self.appDrawController.centerViewController.childViewControllers[0];
```

Now you can access the public methods/properties, so:

```
[[yourClass pinEntryField] becomeFirstResponder];
```

Does this help at all ?

Comment: Well its a bit more complex than that. `rootViewController` is actually a view controller called `LoginViewController` and it presents the `DrawerViewController` so I guess this is not really a solution. Plus there has to be a better way.